# Prevent Default Scroll on body but allow on child div containing chart.js chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, chart.js

I have a number of charts being rendered by Chart.js on my page - these all have the ability to zoom into the chart by using the scroll wheel on the users mouse. I want to be able to stop the user being able to use their scroll wheel on the main html/body of my page, but still allow them to use their scroll wheel in their charts.

I need the scroll bar to be visible so that the user can manually move the scroll bar down.

I use the following code and this works and achieves what I want the page to do.

```
    window.addEventListener("wheel", e=>e.preventDefault(), {
        passive: false
    });
```

However, even though the page behaves like I want it too, I get the following error in Chrome Version 115.0.5790.110 "Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation." whenever I zoom into my charts using the scroll wheel.

Is there anyway to stop the scroll bar from moving when wheel is used on mouse if in the body/html and allow the scroll to work as intended in the charts without the error messaged coming up?

As I say, I expected there to be errors, but not for the page to behave exactly as I want it too, but still with an error every time I use the wheel on the mouse in my chart..

Comment: You stand a much better chance of getting an answer if you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question. Your reader will be able to confirm what you assert, and they have an easy way to test their ideas.